# Dynamic pivot table sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I would like to do data mining. But my data is not useful.
my table structure is something like:

```
date            customerid     age   residence   prosubsclassid   productid       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
21.11.2001       123232323      a         b          2099         23232322 


amount   asset    sales
------------------------
4        34       56
```

Now I have to show the data in this way:

```
prosubsclassid     130207   130208  130209      
                   ------   ------  ------  
1413232              1        3       1     
3435545              2        1       2      
3534344                       3       1      sum(amount)
Column(customerid)
```

I want to convert to tabular form in my data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this. There are support for pivot in SQL server, but the columns still needs to be specified.

Depending on if you want to have a text report or a table with dynamic columns I would group the data per date and prosubsclassid and then using a cursor to build the data.

1. If you want a dynaic table build a dynamic sql query based on the grouped data and run Exec.
2. If you want text report, just concatenate the string data the way you want per line into
   a temp table with one textcolumn and when you are done, select the table.